# A simpler multiply and addition polynomial function

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm working on a project where I have 2 classes, one class for Monomials and another one for polynomials which are built out of monomials.
I would like to make a simpler method for adding and multiplying polynomials, other than my naive method.

```
public class Monomial {

/**
 * @post this.getCoefficient() == coefficient
 * @post for every v, 'a'<=v<='z', isVariable(v) == false
 */
private int[] exponents=new int[26];
private int ceof;

public Monomial(int coefficient) {

    this.ceof=coefficient;
}

public class Polynomial {

/**
 * Creates a polynomial with (safe copies of) the given monomials
 * 
 * @pre monomials != null
 * @pre for all i, 0 <= i < monmials.length : monomials[i] != null
 * @post for all i, 0 <= i < monmials.length : monomials[i].getCoefficient()
 *       == getMonomial(i).getCoefficient()
 * @post for all i,v, 0 <= i < monmials.length, 'a'<=v<='z' :
 *       monomials[i].getDegree(v) == getMonomial(i).getDegree(v)
 */

private Monomial[] monoms; 

public Polynomial(Monomial[] monomials) {
    this.monoms=monomials;
}

/**
 * @return the number of monomials in this polynomial
 */
public int getMonomialCount() {
    return (this.monoms).length; 
}

/**
 * @pre 0<=index < getMonomialCount()
 * @return a safe copy of the monomial at the given index
 */
public Monomial getMonomial(int index) {
    Monomial copy = this.monoms[index].getCopy();
    return copy;
}

/**
 * @pre other != null
 * @post Creates a new Polynomial which is the sum of this polynomial and
 *       other. E.g., the sum of 13b^2x^3z+15 and -4b^2x^3z is
 *       13b^2x^3z+15-4b^2x^3z
 */
public Polynomial add(Polynomial other) {
    Monomial[] sum=new Monomial[this.monoms.length+other.monoms.length];
    boolean stop=false;
    int maincounter = 0;
    int thiscounter = 0;
    int othercounter = 0;
    while(stop==false){
        if(maincounter<=this.monoms.length-1){
            sum[maincounter]= this.monoms[thiscounter].getCopy();
            thiscounter++;
            maincounter++;
        }
        else{
            sum[maincounter]= other.monoms[othercounter].getCopy();
            othercounter++;
            maincounter++;
        }
        if(maincounter>sum.length-1){
            stop=true;

        }

    }
    return new Polynomial(sum);



}

/**
 * @pre other != null
 * @post Creates a new Polynomial which is the product of this polynomial
 *       and other. E.g., the product of 13b^2x^3z+15 and -4b^2x^3z is
 *       -52b^4x^6z^2-60b^2x^3z
 */
public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial other) {
    int coefficient=0;
    int newDegree=0;
    Monomial newMonomial;
    Monomial thisMonomial;
    Monomial otherMonomial;
    Monomial[] result=new Monomial[this.getMonomialCount()*other.getMonomialCount()];

    for(int i=0;i<this.monoms.length;i++){  
        thisMonomial=this.monoms[i];
        for(int j=0;j<other.monoms.length;j++){
            otherMonomial=other.monoms[j];
            coefficient=thisMonomial.getCoefficient()*otherMonomial.getCoefficient();
            newMonomial=new Monomial(coefficient);
            for(int k=0;k<26;k++){
                if(thisMonomial.isVariable((char)('a'+k))==true&&otherMonomial.isVariable((char)('a'+k))==true){
                newDegree=thisMonomial.getDegree((char)('a'+k))+otherMonomial.getDegree((char)('a'+k));
                }
                else{
                    if(thisMonomial.isVariable((char)('a'+k))==true){
                        newDegree=thisMonomial.getDegree((char)('a'+k));
                    }
                    else{
                        newDegree=otherMonomial.getDegree((char)('a'+k));
                    }
                    }
                newMonomial.setDegree((char)('a'+k),newDegree); 
                }
            result[i]=newMonomial.getCopy();
            }
        }
    Polynomial Polyresult;
    Polyresult=new Polynomial(result);
    return Polyresult;
}
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't compile. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

#### The `add` method

A loop with an `if` condition that does one thing for the first `n` elements and does another thing for the next `m` elements would be better as two separate `for` loops for `n` and `m`.
I suggest to rewrite like that.

The `stop` variable is pointless.
Instead of setting it to `false` so that `while` exists,
it would have been better to use `while (true)` and replace `stop = true` with `break`.
(After you rewrite using two `for` loops,
this variable will naturally disappear.)

Don't write `stop == false` in conditions, write simply `!stop`.

#### Formatting

Your code doesn't follow good formatting practices.
It's recommended to put spaces around comparison operators,
for example instead of this:

> ```
>     while(stop==false){
>         if(maincounter<=this.monoms.length-1){
>             sum[maincounter]= this.monoms[thiscounter].getCopy();
>             thiscounter++;
>             maincounter++;
>         }
> ```

Write like this:

```
    while (stop == false) {
        if (maincounter <= this.monoms.length - 1) {
            sum[maincounter] = this.monoms[thiscounter].getCopy();
            thiscounter++;
            maincounter++;
        }
```

The indentation and vertical spacing (blank lines) are also a bit odd.
Use the auto-reformat feature of your IDE to tidy up your code,
for example in Eclipse select all code with `Ctrl-A` and then `Ctrl-Shift-f`.

#### The `multiply` method

The code as you posted is really hard to read. Here it is nicely reformatted:

```
public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial other) {
    int coefficient = 0;
    int newDegree = 0;
    Monomial newMonomial;
    Monomial thisMonomial;
    Monomial otherMonomial;
    Monomial[] result = new Monomial[this.getMonomialCount() * other.getMonomialCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.monoms.length; i++) {
        thisMonomial = this.monoms[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < other.monoms.length; j++) {
            otherMonomial = other.monoms[j];
            coefficient = thisMonomial.getCoefficient() * otherMonomial.getCoefficient();
            newMonomial = new Monomial(coefficient);
            for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
                if (thisMonomial.isVariable((char) ('a' + k)) == true
                        && otherMonomial.isVariable((char) ('a' + k)) == true) {
                    newDegree = thisMonomial.getDegree((char) ('a' + k)) + otherMonomial.getDegree((char) ('a' + k));
                } else {
                    if (thisMonomial.isVariable((char) ('a' + k)) == true) {
                        newDegree = thisMonomial.getDegree((char) ('a' + k));
                    } else {
                        newDegree = otherMonomial.getDegree((char) ('a' + k));
                    }
                }
                newMonomial.setDegree((char) ('a' + k), newDegree);
            }
            result[i] = newMonomial.getCopy();
        }
    }
    Polynomial Polyresult;
    Polyresult = new Polynomial(result);
    return Polyresult;
}
```

Looking from a distance, here's what stands out:

- This piece is used a lot: `isVariable((char) ('a' + k))`. It would be better to create a local variable `char var = (char)('a' + k)` early, and avoid repeating the same logic many times
- Don't write conditions like `if (cond == true)`, simplify to `if (cond)`
- Don't hardcode the number 26, use a constant with a descriptive name instead
- The `Polyresult` variable at the end doesn't follow recommended naming conventions (`camelCase`, should have been `polyresult`), and it's redundant. You could replace the last 3 lines with simply `return new Polynomial(result);`

Answer (score 0):

The code as given does not compile as `getCopy`, `getCoefficient`, `getDegree`, and `isVariable` are missing from class `Monomial`.

Some `toString` method should also be defined, otherwise debugging is a real pain. You're also missing `equals` and `hashCode`.

> @post for every v, 'a'<=v<='z', isVariable(v) == false

Should this explain or obfuscate something?

```
this.ceof=coefficient;
```

Usually, exactly the same name gets used in constructors and setters. And that's why you need the `this` qualifier.

> Creates a polynomial with (safe copies of) the given monomials

Sometimes, copying may be more (or less) efficient, but generally, immutability is the way to go. With an immutable `Monomial` you don't have to hunt bugs caused by forgotten calls to `getCopy`.

```
public Polynomial(Monomial[] monomials) {
    this.monoms=monomials;
}
```

What's worse... the code contradicts the comment.

```
public Monomial getMonomial(int index)
```

A polynomial is *not* an indexed array of monomials. Actually, there's no order, so I'd avoid any public methods giving such an access. This may or may not be possible.

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial other) {
```

You should group the monomials here. What you do is representing `(x)+(x)` as *two* monomials instead of `2*x`.

```
Monomial[] result=new Monomial[this.getMonomialCount()*other.getMonomialCount()];
```

This makes it pretty unusable. From something as simple as `(x+y)*(x-y)` you get `x*x - x*y + x*y - y*y` instead of `x*x - y*y`. With every operation, your polynomial grows, never to shrink again.

```
if(thisMonomial.isVariable((char)('a'+k))==true&&otherMonomial.isVariable((char)('a'+k))==true){
                newDegree=thisMonomial.getDegree((char)('a'+k))+otherMonomial.getDegree((char)('a'+k));
                }
                else{
                    if(thisMonomial.isVariable((char)('a'+k))==true){
                        newDegree=thisMonomial.getDegree((char)('a'+k));
                    }
                    else{
                        newDegree=otherMonomial.getDegree((char)('a'+k));
                    }
                    }
```

You're needlessly special-casing degree 0, which blows your expression to something terribly complicated... and also broken: In case of both degrees being 0, you simply keep `newDegree` from the previous iteration as you missed this case. *Always minimize the scope.* Simply using

```
char v = (char)('a'+k);
int newDegree = thisMonomial.getDegree(v) + otherMonomial.getDegree(v);
```

would do.

### What I'd suggest?

Create an immutable class `UnitMonomial` (monomial with coefficient equal 1) with a method `multiply(UnitMonomial)` and represent Polynomial as `Map<UnitMonomial, Integer>`. This allows you to simplify the results of all operations.